# Run SH script in a new terminal window

Tags: python-3.x, raspberry-pi, sh, raspbian

I am currently using crontab to run a SH script at boot which navigates to the path of my python script, switches to a different python environment and runs my python script, although it works perfectly fine it runs hidden without a terminal for me to monitor whatever the python interpreter prints like errors, how could I make it so the python interpreter points at a newly opened terminal window?

Here is my SH script (runs with the bash interpreter, not sh):

```
#!/bin/sh
cd /
cd /home/pi/Desktop/Juvia-py
source defenv/bin/activate
python3 juvia.py &
```

and my crontab entry:

```
@reboot bash /home/pi/launcher.sh
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to record errors, you could [pipe STDOUT and STDERR to files](https://askubuntu.com/questions/625224/how-to-redirect-stderr-to-a-file), something like

```
python3 juvia.py >stdout.log 2>stderr.log &
```

But if you wanted to open it in a separate window so you could interact you would need to manage STDIN more creatively.

Comment: Redirecting stdout is definitely the most sensible way to do this. OP could use tail -f to view the script's output as it happens from a terminal.